# Converting JSON to XML and vice versa using Jackson API and JAXB Annotations

Tags: java, xml, json, jaxb, jackson

I'm trying to write a code which can take either XML or JSON input and output JSON or XML respectively. I.e, if I give XML it should give back JSON, and if I give JSON it should give XML output.

I was told this is possible using Jackson API and JAXB Annotations. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Below is an example of how you can use MOXy's JSON-binding to support this use case.

**JAVA MODEL**

Below is an example domain model annotated with JAXB metadata.  The same metadata will be used for both the object-to-XML and object-to-JSON conversions.

***Customer***

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

    private int id;

    private String firstName;

    @XmlElement(nillable=true)
    private String lastName;

    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

}
```

***PhoneNumber***

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PhoneNumber {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String type;

    @XmlValue
    private String number;

}
```

**XML INPUT**

Below is the XML input that we will use.  Note how the `xsi:nil` attribute is used on the `lastName` element to indicate a `null` value.  Also note how the `phoneNumbers` element has a `type` attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>
   <id>123</id>
   <firstName>Jane</firstName>
   <lastName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
   <phoneNumbers type="work">555-1111</phoneNumbers>
</customer>
```

**DEMO CODE**

***jaxb.properties***

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html):

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

***Demo***

The following demo code will convert the XML to the domain model and then back to JSON.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum14734741/input.xml");
        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
    }

}
```

**JSON OUTPUT**

Note how the `null` value for the `lastName` key is represented as proper JSON.  Also note how the `type` key doesn't contain any special indicator corresponding to it being an XML attribute in the XML representation.

```
{
   "id" : 123,
   "firstName" : "Jane",
   "lastName" : null,
   "phoneNumbers" : [ {
      "type" : "work",
      "value" : "555-1111"
   } ]
}
```

Comment: @RSyed - I also have an example on GitHub that you may find helpful:  https://github.com/bdoughan/blog20110819

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but don't think of it as converting between XML and JSON -- this is pretty much the wrong thing to do, causing compatibility issues -- but that of converting Java Objects (POJOs) to/from JSON and XML. You can use one or two tools for this: one common combination is to use Jackson for JSON, and JAXB for XML, to use their respective strengths.

It is also possible to use a single tool; Blaise explained how JAXB implementations can help.
Similarly, you can use Jackson for both: for XML part you need to use [Jackson XML module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml).
With Jackson, you can use Jackson's own annotations (prefered), or JAXB annotations for compatibility; both work for XML and JSON use cases.

Use of XML module with Jackson does not differ a lot from default JSON processing, except that you will need `XmlMapper` sub-class of `ObjectMapper`.
If using this from JAX-RS (like Jersey), you can use [Jackson JAX-RS XML provider](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider).