# Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: eclipselink.media-type value: application/json

Tags: java, json, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I'm attempting to follow the example located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734741/converting-json-to-xml-and-vice-versa-using-jackson-api-and-jaxb-annotation) but get an javax.xml.bind.PropertyException. I receive this exception because of the following line of code:

```
marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
```

I have literally copy/pasted the example listed above so my code is exactly what you see there. Searching SO and Google for this has not been helpful, and thought I'd bring this to the geniuses at SO for some help. Any help would be most appreciated, (de)serialization with JSON and XML with json.org, Jackson, and JAXB has turned into a black and bottomless pit that has consumed almost a month of my life.

My first impression was that I wasn't properly specifying the eclipselink runtime ([as described here](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/runtime001.htm#CACFEGHC)) but that didn't produce a solution.

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: eclipselink.media-type value: application/json
   at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.setProperty(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:358)
   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.setProperty(MarshallerImpl.java:527)
   at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:17)
```

This is what I'm doing,

[image]

Comment: are you using EclipseLink 2.4.0 or above?

Comment: @sasankad - Good catch.  The exception being thrown is an RI exception (`com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime` package) so EclipseLink MOXy is not being picked up as the JAXB provider.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan, Quite a few people have come across this issue

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to have the EclipseLink jars (2.4.0 or newer) on your class path, and a `jaxb.properties` file in the same package as the classes used to bootstrap the`JAXBContext` with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Below is a link to an example on GitHub that you can run to see everything working:

- https://github.com/bdoughan/blog20110819

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Did u see my PrintScr? I have downloaded the last EclipseLink and have created the file named jaxb.properties. What  could it be wrong?

Comment: Please elaborate the 'problem with jaxb'.

Comment: To make it painfully obvious: the `jaxb.properties` file must be in the same package in the *resources tree*, not in the *src tree*. See Blaise's example code.

Comment: Clarification `jaxb.properties` has to be in the package of the **model** classes. So in your example in the class where `Customer` class is. I tried to put the properties files to the package where my class corresponding to `HelloWorld` was.

Answer (score 14):

To my main method I added (you could also use `-D`):

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.bind.context.factory","org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory");
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format the code in your answer and consider explaining why your answer works. Also, please look through the [how to answer guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to add a jaxb.properties file, you can do this all in Java code. This is especially helpful for legacy systems where you don't want to risk affecting the classpath by introducing a new jaxb.properties file.

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.xmlmodel.ObjectFactory;

//Set the various properties you want
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);

//Create a Context using the properties
JAXBContext jaxbContext = 
    JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[]  {
       MyClass.class,    ObjectFactory.class}, properties);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

//Marshall the object
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(myObject, stringWriter);
String json = stringWriter.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the versions and works with maven for me with:

```
    openjdk version "17.0.4" 2022-07-19
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.4+8-Ubuntu-120.04)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.4+8-Ubuntu-120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

mvn:

```
        .
        .
        .
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        .
        .
        .
```

I post this because I got the mentioned exception above with the newest versions and found no solution. Maybe this setup helps.