# json to xml and xml to json inverse function java

Tags: java, json, xml, server

Currently I am working on server side in Java with an API that accepts only XML request,and I get data in JSON format from the client side.The problem is that the API accepts a very specific format that I have to match,the thing that I would like to do is to get an JSON request and parse it to XML and visa versa in such matter:

```
[jsonToXML(x) = XMLToJson^{-1}(x)]
```

Is there any functions that hold this propety?

Comment: This may help :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734741/converting-json-to-xml-and-vice-versa-using-jackson-api-and-jaxb-annotations

Comment: @akhil Does the property holds?I made it possible, convert xml to json and visa versa by JSONObject,but in that way the property doesn't hold at all